# Lumen: Method where() not supported

Tags: routes, router, lumen

I am trying to create a route for everything that starts with `assets` and catch every succeeding strings into `{path}` variable. The codes is something like below:

```
$router->get('/assets/{path}', 'AssetController@show')
   ->where('path', '(.*)');
```

I found out `where` is not supported by Lumen and triggers this error:

```
Call to undefined method Laravel\Lumen\Routing\Router::where()
```

Is there a way that I can accomplish this on Lumen?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out with the following codes:

```
$router->get('/assets/{path:.+}', 'AssetController@show');
```